# NSTimer with multiple time intervals in a sequence

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, intervals

Without creating multiple `NSTimer` instances, how would one achieve an `NSTimer` to fire a specific or multiple method with different intervals in a sequence. For example method1 (0.3 sec), method2 (0.5), method3 (0.7) and so on.

I would appreciate if someone could please share any example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final goal is with this but after reading your question **I would recommend to try the following way**, maybe this is what you'd look for.

you should put this code where you normally wanted to start the same `NSTimer` class with different intervals (what is not possible, unfortunately).

```
{
    // ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(method1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];
    [self performSelector:@selector(method2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
    [self performSelector:@selector(method3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.7f];
    // ...
}
```

and when need to unschedule all those selectors queued, use this code.

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already used the same code, Additionally I've added how to cancel the queued requests.

Answer (score 4):

`NSTimer` itself does not provide that functionality, it fires either once or repeatedly at fixed intervals. You will require multiple timers to achieve this effect, or move away from `NSTimer` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

i beleive you should pass current time interval to the fired selector and further handle it there. if time interval is 0.3 you call method1, 0.5 - method2, there's most likely no other way to implement this

Answer (score -1):

Make a wrapper to wrap the `NSTimer` method call like this:

> ```
> - (void) CallTimerWithTimeInterval:(float) interval andSelector:(NSString *)methodName 
> {
> SEL selector = selectorFromString(methodName);
>     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(selector) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
> }
> ```

You can call this method and pass the interval and selector method as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the other method. Btw if I use this method, Do I have to stop or nil the timer it creates at any stage? how would I achieve that?

Comment: To stop the timer you need to set the `repeats` parameter to `NO`. You can do that by adding another parameter to the wrapper function. `- (void) CallTimerWithTimeInterval:(float) interval andSelector:(NSString *)methodName withRepeats:(BOOL) YESorNO`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just being curious whether this approach is better than the one I chose. 

The scenario is that I would have to call this method multiple times lets say 10 times. It will create 10 copies of NSTimer scheduled to fire on particular time. Now if middle of somewhere I wish to terminate the timers all at once, repeats NO might not help as its stopping it for re-occurrences. 

Once 10 copies are scheduled, how would I stop it. Make an instance variable of NSTimer and then send a nil message?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. If you want to invalidate multiple timers all using a single command than this might help.
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26645-invalidate-multiple-nstimer.html

Comment: If `methodName` is an `NSString` you need to use `NSSelectorFromString`, or, you need to change `methodName` to be of type `SEL`.

Comment: @dreamlax thank you for your advice. My mistake. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

create an timer with selector with timeinterval = 0.1
from there in the selector method, you can check by keeping a static float variable and add 0.1 to it everytime like:

```
static CGFloat counter= 0;

counter+= 0.1;
```

then check the counter value and call ur methods..

```
if(0.3 == counter)
{
    [self callMethod1];
}
else if(0.5 == counter)
{
    [self callMethod2];
}
else if(0.7 == counter)
{
    [self callMethod3];
}
...
...
..
..
```

Comment: Comparing floats with == is asking for trouble because they are binary approximations of the decimal representation.

Comment: but we are only adding 0.1 within our code and counter values are not approximation coming out of the calculations based on undecided factors such as a timer. counter values are not dependent on timer fire interval rather than it depends on how many times method is invoked. it is like `i += 1;` so there should not be any problems.

Comment: Better to use an integer, increment the integer by 1 every 100 milliseconds, and use `if ((counter % 3) == 0)` etc...

Comment: @samfisher: Did you know that `0.2` cannot be represented in a float exactly? In binary, it is a repeating pattern 0.0011001100110011...  [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary).

Comment: @samfisher I'm not talking about timer inaccuracies I'm talking about decimal number representation inaccuracies as mentioned by dreamlax. 0.1 would be something along the lines of 0.10000000000000001 or 0.99999999999999998.