# iPhone- Call Method With Increasingly Less Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app and I want to change the background color at increasingly fast rates. Basically, I want the background color to change after a three second delay, then a 2.9 second delay, etc....

So, what I thought was that I would make a random integer that I use to pick the random color (i.e. each integer corresponds to a color). This works fine, definitely no problems here. The problem is with the delays. I tried to do a bunch of things, but I can't wrap my head around the logic of it.

I apologize for not posting my code, but my code is very complicated right now and would take pages of context to understand (probably part of the problem). I am looking for a simple solution to this.

Comment: Downvoted for the "Please include code in your solution" - The point of StackOverflow is not to do the work for you, but provide help.

Comment: some example? pseudo code?

Comment: you should post the code even if its messy thats fine as long as you indent it at least

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536580/nstimer-with-multiple-time-intervals-in-a-sequence

Answer (score 0):

GCD has a method to dispatch a block after a delay:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
    });
```

You could wrap this into a recursive function that terminates at 0:

```
#define SECONDS_DECREMENT .1f

- (void)changeColorAfter:(float)seconds
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [self changeBackgroundToRandomColor];

        if (seconds > SECONDS_DECREMENT)
        {
            [self changeColorAfter:seconds - SECONDS_DECREMENT];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a recursive function that calls itself every x amount of time. Something like this:

```
-(void)updateBackgroundWithInterval:(NSNumber *)interval {

    //Get the interval float value
    float intervalFloat = [interval floatValue];

    //Update your background and do whatever else

    NSLog(@"Hit interval = %.2f", intervalFloat);

    //Make your interval smaller
    intervalFloat -= 0.1;

    //Continue if the interval will be >= your minimum value (we'll say 0)
    if (intervalFloat > 0) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateBackgroundWithInterval:) withObject:@(intervalFloat) afterDelay:intervalFloat];
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it using something like this:

```
[self updateBackgroundWithInterval:@2.0];
```

I'd also recommend having a `BOOL` flag of some sort as an instance variable or property of the class that the `updateBackgroundWithInterval:` function checks each time, that way you can stop the process if the user exits the view, etc.